# Installing cairo 1.8.6 on CentOS 5.6

Tags: installation, centos, cairo

I may be blind today, but I can't figure how to upgrade my installed cairo 1.2.4 version on CentOS 5.6 to 1.8.6. Cannot find any reps providing the latest version of cairo.

Can someone help me out please? node-canvas is requiring it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely your only hope is to build it yourself.

Understand that CentOS/RHEL 5.x is over 4 years old at this point. The world has largely moved on, especially for graphics-related stuff. I'm entirely unsurprised that you can't find packages for recent versions of Cairo.

If you can't build it yourself, the next best thing I could recommend is to either wait for CentOS 6 (or buy RHEL 6, if you like), or switch distributions (going to Fedora wouldn't be a big leap, but would get you up-to-date packages, it's a good choice for a desktop).